# PHP execution very slow with simple hello world script and no internet connectivity

Tags: php, networking

I have an application that does a lot of requests to external hostnames, and because of this i needed to test the behavior of this application when there was no internet connectivity. So i went ahead and blocked internet access for the server that runs the app on my router, so that i could still access the server from within the LAN. However I'm facing an issue because even with a simple script as this

```
<?php
echo "Hello World!";
```

I can never access that page when on the same lan. Chrome just loads forever. However I've no problems accessing the server via Putty over SSH from the same LAN, so it is not blocked on the LAN. I can also write a random non existing page into my browser on the client, that points to the server, and i get a 404 error at once.

Its like even though my code, as above, doesn't make any requests externally it is still dependant on the WAN being available, which i do not want

EDIT: It should be noted that the server is running Lighttpd as the main webserver along with PHP7.0

Comment: I suspect some extension are blocking page load when there's no internet connectivity.  Try incognito mode with all extensions disabled.

Comment: You mean in Chrome ? Remember that my client machine has full internet access. I've only blocked internet acces to the Server

Comment: Ah, I see.  I suspect then that your server is still trying to access whatever locations on the internet it needs, which results in connection timeouts.  This can take anywhere from 15 seconds to several minutes per connection attempt.  Try using curl or wget or similar to access your URL.

Comment: Apache has a "lookup hostnames" feature for access logging. Maybe Lighty has something similar? (Who runs Lighty these days?!)

Comment: Is there an alternative til Lighty, which is more light than apache? Nginx?